# SVN commit trouble - Base checksum mismatch

Tags: svn

I finished some work and I wanted to commit it but SVN commit failed. I tried some advices without any luck. I am using Android Studio.

What I have done before the error occured:

- upgraded debian to the latest version
- fixed SSL error (see [my previous question](https://superuser.com/q/1055171/283411))
- installed LetsEncrypt certificate
- added new directory with file to local SVN repository
- modified many files in local rep
- reverted add of new directory
- removed one Test file from local repository

Then I tried to commit all changes and it failed that deleted test is out of date. I ran `svn up`and repeated commit but it failed with infamous `Base checksum mismatch`error. I found some advices so I moved local repository away and provided fresh checkout. I copied modified files back (without SVN repo files) and tried commit again - same behaviour.

Then I went to server and ran `svnadmin verify` on my repository. I checked out the repository again, I deleted just the test file and attempted to commit it - fails with `svn: E155011: File is out of date`. It makes no sense. What else can I try?

```
[Mon Mar 28 09:56:12.444710 2016] [dav:error] [pid 15202] [client 82.99.:53925] Unable to PUT new contents for /svn/xx/!svn/wrk/63c738bc-5301-0010-80f14d746ece7f88/repo/app/src/androidTest/java//FormulaTest.java.  [403, #0]
[Mon Mar 28 09:56:12.444759 2016] [dav:error] [pid 15202] [client 82.99.:53925] Could not prepare to write the file  [500, #200014]
[Mon Mar 28 09:56:12.444767 2016] [dav:error] [pid 15202] [client 82.99.:53925] Base checksum mismatch on '/repo/app/src/androidTest//FormulaTest.java':\n   
expected:  7290b9a9dd43b2c9236fa6f55417a398\n     
actual:  4874627488b5b5a8b58e374685c9b889\n  [500, #200014]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I attempted to checkout 1.6 SVN format and then commit worked. Inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29400059/1639556