# Apache SSL error: Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client?

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, ssl, certificate

I protect my wordpress administration by a client certificate. I had a trouble in march after upgrading from Wheezy to Jessie but it has been [solved](https://superuser.com/a/1055198/283411) and everything ran well until my letsencrypt certificate expired.

I ran a letsencrypt client and it modified apache configuration files as well. The client certificate protected path stopped working on SSL error. Unfortunately I do not have a backup of previous configuration.

I spent few hours but without success. This answer probably explains the fault but I am unable to apply it in my scenerio.

```
ssl_engine_kernel.c(1908): [client 213.220.230.83:50427] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername found
ssl_engine_kernel.c(1841): [client 213.220.230.83:50427] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
ssl_engine_kernel.c(1841): [client 213.220.230.83:50428] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
ssl_engine_kernel.c(243): [client 213.220.230.83:50427] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 2 (server www.literak.cz:443)
ssl_engine_kernel.c(591): [client 213.220.230.83:50427] AH02255: Changed client verification type will force renegotiation
[client 213.220.230.83:50427] AH02221: Requesting connection re-negotiation
ssl_engine_kernel.c(791): [client 213.220.230.83:50427] AH02260: Performing full renegotiation: complete handshake protocol (client does support secure renegotiation)
[client 213.220.230.83:50427] AH02226: Awaiting re-negotiation handshake
ssl_engine_kernel.c(1908): [client 213.220.230.83:50427] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername found
[client 213.220.230.83:50427] AH02261: Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client!?
```

The configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
NameVirtualHost 77.93.226.222:80
<VirtualHost 77.93.226.222:443>

  DocumentRoot /var/www-data/wordpress
  <Directory /var/www-data/wordpress>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
  </Directory>

  SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/leos.pem
    <Location /wp-admin>
      SSLVerifyClient require
      SSLVerifyDepth  1
    </Location>

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live//fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/privkey.pem
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, that is weird. I found this [topic](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/383348), where somebody had a problem when a certificate was not imported. I checked it and it was my case as well. The certificate disappeared from my chrome.